# MVC there is validation error but request sent to the server and ModelState.IsValid is true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am using htmlHelper ValidationMessageFor. There is validation error but request went to the server and ModelState.IsValid becomes true. Is this possible that ModelState.IsVaid becomes false if there is some kind of Validation Error. I can do that at client side but I want to develop it on server side.

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Wrong Email")]
public string ElectronicMailAddress { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ElectronicMailAddress, new { @class = "control-label"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ElectronicMailAddress, new { @class = "form-control"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElectronicMailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CallingFunction()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {........}
}
```

Comment: You can use ModelState.AddModelError to add custom errors in controller.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "request went to the server". Is is that the Form POST got sent to the Controller (which is normal behaviour, and also how it should be). Or is it that the Controller processed the item as if nothing was wrong (which is what YOU must program, probably with at least a little bit of `if (ModelState.IsValid) { ... }` thrown in).

Comment: See here for more on how to use `ModelState.IsValid`: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: @Peter B  I have Edit My Question

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "validation error." If you're using, say, Entity Framework and you're getting a validation error from _that_, it means you're violating a database constraint. Otherwise, you haven't shown enough to make anything other than a wild guess as to what maybe causing the error you're getting.

Comment: @Tieson T Validation errors  mean it's violating the MVC data annotation but model state isvalid property return true.

Comment: You not passing any model to that method - it does not even have any parameters! How could there possibly be any `ModelStateErrors`

Comment: You have not shown the relevant code to understand what you trying to do. What is the model in the view? Why are you calling a method that returns json?. Why are you calling a POST method without even passing a model to it? Why are you calling it if its invalid on the client? (you should be checking `$('form').valid()` before making your ajax request)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Html.EditorFor` for the validation to work instead of `Html.TextBoxFor`. Also you need to make sure the below scripts are loaded into your page. Either by bundle syntax or regular references

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script> // your version of Jquery
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: even Html.EditorFor works the same as  Html.TextBoxFor and yes i am using all these scripts in my cshtml. it show validation error "Wrong Email" but after this the request went to the server. and modelstate.isvalid becomes true. even i use Html.EditorFor